# Adding items to existing collection - The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I am using latest ef core 7.0.11. When running the CanInsertOrderline2 test I get the following error.

**The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded**

But the other test (CanInsertOrderline1) works as expected.

If I add the orderline to the context it works as it should.

```
secondContext.OrderLines.Add(secondOrder.OrderLines[0]);
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

```
 [Test]
 public void CanInsertOrderline2()
 {
     //This Throws an exception 
     var dbContext = new OrderContext();
     ResetDatabase(dbContext);

     var theOrder = new Order();
     dbContext.Orders.Add(theOrder);
     dbContext.SaveChanges();

     Assert.That(new OrderContext().Orders.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));

     var secondContext = new OrderContext();
     var secondOrder = secondContext.Orders
                                    .Include(i => i.OrderLines)
                                    .First();

     secondOrder.OrderLines.Add(new OrderLine());
     secondContext.SaveChanges();

     var otherContext = new OrderContext();
     Assert.That(otherContext.Orders.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1), "Order");
     Assert.That(otherContext.OrderLines.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1), "OrderLines");
 }


 [Test]
 public void CanInsertOrderline1()
 {
     var dbContext = new OrderContext();
     ResetDatabase(dbContext);

     var theOrder = new Order();
     dbContext.Orders.Add(theOrder);

     theOrder.OrderLines.Add(new OrderLine());

     dbContext.SaveChanges();

     var otherContext = new OrderContext();
     Assert.That(otherContext.Orders.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
     Assert.That(otherContext.OrderLines.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
 }

public class Order
{
    public Order()
    { }

    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; } = new();
}


public class OrderLine
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public string ProductText { get; set; } = "ProductText";
}
```

Comment: You should write `unit tests` for the methods and services you created , but it seems that you are writing tests for `EF Core` !!!.

Comment: Well, obviously the tests discovered OP is doing something that leads to an unexpected result. Nothing bad about that.

Comment: Do you have a primary key?  With a primary key you can only have one row with the key.    So you need to use Update when key already exists instead of Add.

Comment: The Id will be PK in database so there is a PK. And the new item I add to the collection will get its id from Guid.NewGuid() so it will not exist in the database.